# MS Access - como obter intervalo de data de 30 dias

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Preciso coletar pedidos registrados de uma tabela com o nome PedidosTalao nos últimos 30 dias.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Procure incluir mais informações para deixar clara a sua dúvida, como campos da sua tabela, tentativas anteriores, etc. Visite a página [ask] para mais informações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua consulta, utilize a expressão [`SomData()`](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/access-help/funcao-dateadd-HA001228810.aspx) (ou [`DateAdd()`](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/access-help/funcao-dateadd-HA001228810.aspx) no Access em inglês) como critério na coluna da data seguinte forma:

```
>= SomData("d"; -30; Data() )
```

Ele faz um `WHERE` do campo retornando todas as datas dos últimos 30 dias. 
O tipo do campo deve ser `Data`

Comment: Obg pelas dicas +gmsantos, e resolvi assim:

SELECT 
 pt.id as Pedido,
 pt.Data
 FROM 
 (PedidosTalao pt
 INNER JOIN SubPedidosTalao sub
 ON pt.ID = sub.IdPedido)
 INNER JOIN Clientes cli
 ON cli.Codigo = pt.Cliente
 WHERE cdate(format(pt.Data,'mm/dd/yyyy')) between Date() - 30 and Date()
 ORDER BY 1 DESC